# Azure Functions error - establishing connection failed

Tags: azure-functions, azure-private-dns-zone

I have Azure Data Factory, which calls Azure Durable Functions.
I had success working connection until Terraform did some unknown changes.

Where the issue could be?

> Error in Azure Data Factory:
> An error occured while sending the request.
> Unable to connect to the remote server.
> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
> period
> of time, or establishing connection failed because connected host has failed to response
> xx.xx.xx.xx:xxx.

Comment: Did you try to call the Azure Function Separately? as in go to the test blade and invoke it to make sure it works? 
You can also disable this activity in DF and check if it will work

Answer (score 0):

> Error in Azure Data Factory: An error occured while sending the request. Unable to connect to the remote server. A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or establishing connection failed because connected host has failed to response xx.xx.xx.xx:xxx.

I believe this error occurs due to firewall issues like some blocking rules didn't allow it to reach out to the data source. Please try using the following steps:

- Allow access from all networks under Firewalls and Virtual Networks of the storage account.
- As mentioned in the [Azure Data Factory Security and access control troubleshooting guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/security-and-access-control-troubleshoot-guide?tabs=data-factory#connection-error-in-public-endpoint), there are 2 cause like public endpoint in Managed VNet is not reliable to Azure Blob Storage and the other is Azure Blob Storage, Data Lake Gen2 are not supported through public endpoint connection from the Managed VNet Service. Please check the troubleshooting guide for the few workarounds given by Microsoft for this kind of error.